# What is the probability that you and your opponent draw two cards each and the two hands sum 21

Tags: probability

The problem:

You deal yourself two cards, and your opponent two cards. Your opponent reveals that the sum of those two cards is 21; what is the probability that the sum of your two cards is 21? What is the probability that you both have 21?

My Solution:
Let $A$ be the event that your opponents sum is 21. Let $B$ be the event that you sum is 21.

$$P(B\mid A) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A)} = \frac{(16)(4)(15)(3)}{{{52\choose 2}}{{50\choose 2}}}\frac{{52\choose 2}}{(16)(4)} = \frac{(15)(3)}{{50\choose 2}} $$

And the probability of both

$$\frac{(16)(4)(15)(3)}{{{52\choose 2}}{{50\choose 2}}}.$$

However the solution on the back of the book says the solution to the first problem is $$\frac{(15)(3)}{{52\choose 2}}.$$

And the solution to the second problem
$$\frac{(16)(4)(15)(3)}{{{52\choose 2}}{{52\choose 2}}}.$$

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I disagree.  Different decks would imply a numerator of $(16)^2 \times (4^2)$.   My **blind guess** is that the book has a typo in the second factor in the denominator, which should instead be $$\binom{50}{2}.$$  The book apparently made a similar mistake in the first problem.

Comment: @user2661923  Good point about the two decks.  However, both the answers in the book appear to be wrong.  It seems strange that that the authors would make more than one typographical error.

Comment: To the OP: for what it's worth, I think that your analysis of this problem is accurate.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig One explanation is that the same typo, of having a 2nd (wrong) factor of $~\displaystyle \binom{52}{2}~$ in the first problem led, by cancellation to the resulting 1st problem mistake.  So, it is plausible that a single mistake by the author caused both wrong answers.

Comment: @user2661923  I agree that a single error could cause both wrong answers.  However, I think you are being a bit generous in calling it a typo.  Hitting $9$ instead of $0$ is a typo; hitting $2$ instead of $0$ is not.